# Best approach cascade deleting related entity in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cascading-deletes

Need advice of the best approach how to design DB for the following scenario:

Following below DB structure exmaple (it's not real just explain problem)

```
File
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY...,
  Name VARCHAR(), 
  TypeId SMALLINT, 
  ...
  /*other common fields*/
)
FileContent
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY...,
  FileId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES File(Id) NOT NULL ON DELETE CASCADE UNIQUE,
  Content VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL, 
)

Book 
(
   Id INT PRIMARY KEY..., 
   Name VARCHAR(255), 
   Author VARCHAR(255)
   ...
   CoverImageId FK REFERENCES File(Id),
)

BookPageType
(
   Id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY..., 
   Name VARCHAR(50), 
)

BookPage
(
   Id INT PRIMARY KEY..., 
   TypyId TINYINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BookPageType(Id), 
   BookId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Book(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   Name VARCHAR(100),
   CreatedDate DATETIME2,
   ... 
   /*other common fields*/  
)

BookPage1
(
  Id PRIMARAY KEY REFERENCES BookPage(Id) NOT NULL  ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FileId PRIMARAY KEY REFERENCES File(Id)
  ... 
  /* other specific fileds */
)
...
BookPageN
(
  Id PRIMARAY KEY REFERENCES BookPage(Id) NOT NULL ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  ImageId PRIMARAY KEY REFERENCES File(Id),
  ... 
  /* other specific fileds */
)
```

Now question is I want to delete Book with all pages and data (and it works good with delete cascade), but how to make cascade delete the associated files also (1 to 1 relentionship). 
Here I see following approaches:

1. Add file to every table when I use it, but I don't want to copy file
   schema for every table
2. Add foreign keys to the File table (instead of page for example), but since I use file for e.g. in   10 tables I will have 10 foreign keys in file table. This also not good
3. Use triggers, what I don't wnat to do

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have a 1 to 1 relationship between file and book, why do you need a file table?

Comment: It's used also in another tables (in Pages for eample). Book have cover photo, but pages in book may have also another images, logo, attachments etc (usually it's 1 to 1 reletionship, one logo per page)

Comment: When designing databases you can't go on usually.  If you design it as a 1 to 1, you only have that option.  So what is it? 1 to 1, or 1 to many or many to many.  Can the same image be on multiple pages?  Can a given page have multiple images?  do you really have a separate table for each page?

Comment: If a file can be used on the cover of book 1 and a page of book 2, attempting to cascade delete is perhaps not the best idea avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

If such necessary is appeared maybe it seems you need refactor your base.
You said this example is not real and I'll not ask about N tables for pages though it's strange. If not all files have 1 to 1 relationship and so you need remove only a file that other book does not refer to, it's sounds like a job for a trigger.

Comment: Maybe it's not good names for example... but I've change only the names of tables from real DB

Answer (score 0):

So what you have defined is a many-to-many relationship between `BookPage` and `File`. this is a result of the one-to-many relationship between `BookPage` and `BookPageN` and then the one-to-many relationship between `File` and `BookPageN`. To get the relationships you say you want in the text, you need to turn the relationship around to point from `BookPageN` to `File`.  Maybe instead of having so many `BookPageN` tables you could find a way to consolidate them into a single table. Maybe just use the `BookPage` table. Just allow nulls for the fields that are optional.

Comment: It would be very big table, with aproximatly ~ 100 columns and it is growth

Comment: if an entity has 100 or 1000 attributes, it is still better to put them into the same table.  As long as they are real attributes.  Make sure you normalize the tables.  Remove any repeating attributes to detail tables, etc.